# Where On Unique Property not working in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph in neo4j with 100 million nodes. I created an unique constraint on a property but when I use the property in my where clause it returns no rows. I know it has a result but returns no rows.
my Cypher query is like below:

```
MATCH(n:Person{PK:'1'})
RETURN n
```

or

```
MATCH(n:Person)
WHERE n.PK='1'
RETURN n
```

Comment: Maybe a String/Integer problem? Does `MATCH (n:Person {PK:1})` work?

Comment: Perhaps you could share some more detail, such as the results of `:schema` in the browser? What cypher did you use to create the constraint? What is the node data that you believe should match the index?

Comment: Can you show us a few `Person` nodes? What does this return? `MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n LIMIT 5;`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use `:schema` in the browser to check your constraint?

Also note that it is case sensitive, both for the label and the key.

Comment: yes, I checked it. Index and constraint is created and I considered to case sensitivie for the label and the key but I don't get any rows yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have a unique constraint doesn't mean that you have data, in this case a person, with that property. Try just pulling up a person and seeing what properties are set.

```
match (p:Person) return p limit 5;
```

My suspicion is that the problem is in how you are creating the Person nodes. Can you share that code with us?

Comment: I found the problem after tow days. key values on the constraints have many spaces that make my search wrong. I removed the spaces with trim and then everything was OK.